# Angular Multiple md-table using mdSort in Same Component

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have an Angular app and basically 1 component that submits that multiple tabs. The first tab submits a request and then populates 2 tables, each on a separate tab. I'm using the material functions like MdSort, MdPaginator, and a filter on each table. Based on Angular's documentation, it has you select the mdSort element like this:

```
@ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;
```

And the html is

```
<md-table id="datatable" #datatable [dataSource]="resultDataSource" mdSort>
```

This works fine if there is only 1 table in the component, but since I have 2 tables, how do I correctly select the sort element for each to provide to the data source? If the answer is to use separate components for each table, how do I pass the result data to the data source in the other components?

Comment: The idea of components is to use the same component for each table.  You would then pass the data (resultDataSource) as an input on the component.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up solving this by moving the content of each tab (and thus each table) into its own component with its own datasource. The request component html used selectors for the children components as follows:

```
<md-tab label="Results">
  <md-card class="datacard resultscard">
    <md-card-content>
      <app-result></app-result>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</md-tab>

<md-tab label="Alerts">
  <md-card class="datacard resultscard">
    <md-card-content>
      <app-alert></app-alert>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</md-tab>
```

Then in the request component I referenced the child components using ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(RequestComponent) resultsChild: ResultComponent;
@ViewChild(AlertComponent) alertsChild: AlertComponent;
```

Then called a method I had included with each component to send the data returned from the request to these components so they could add it to their datasource for their respective table. Doesn't really answer the original question, but it was a workaround for what I needed to accomplish.